# Submit an array of objects to mutations in GraphQL - Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

I'm having hard time passing an array of objects to a mutation in GraphQL on Flutter, currently I'm handling it just like how I used to handle it in RESTful, just passing a list of objects that have "toJson()" method, this throws an error of type mismatch, then tried encoding the list and decoding it, didn't work.

any ideas on how it's done? I can't seem to find documentation about my case.

this is the schema:

```
input InvitationEmployeeInput {
  employees: [NewEmployeeInput]
  merchantId: String!
  storeId: String!
}

type InvitationEmployeePayload {
  nodes: [Employee!]!
}

type Mutation {
 invitationEmployee(input: InvitationEmployeeInput!): InvitationEmployeePayload
}
```

and here is the mutation I'm sending against the schema

```
String inviteEmployeeMutation = """ 
    mutation inviteEmployee (
        \$storeId: String!,
        \$merchantId: String!                 
        \$employees: [NewEmployeeInput]     
    ) {
        invitationEmployee (
            input: {
                storeId: \$storeId
                merchantId: \$merchantId         
                employees: \$employees
            }
        ) {
            nodes {
                id         
                firstName         
                lastName         
                email     
                mobile
            }         
        }
    }                 
""";
```

Comment: it's listed in the question, this is the schema not the dart code @sp00m

Comment: I updated the question, kindly check it again @sp00m

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
   String delivery= r'''
      mutation list($list:[DeliveryTmpInput]){
      createDeliveryList(
        deliveryList: $list
      )
    }''';
```

Code:

```
List requestedBody= [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  DeliveryTmpInput deliveryTmp= DeliveryTmpInput(
      '1234',
      'Vodka',
      '28',
   );

  requestedBody.add(deliveryTmp);
}

runMutation(<String, dynamic>{
  "list": requestedBody
});
```

Comment: This item of code had been split by a placeholder from the Stack Overflow editor (specifically for adding a quote block). If it was intended to be a single file you can remove that.